# How to read File and convert it to Hashmap?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I want to save my Hashmap data to File by using this code:

```
File file = new File(getDir("data", MODE_PRIVATE), "map");    
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
outputStream.writeObject(map);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

The problem is, I don't know how to read that File and convert it back to the hashmap. How can this be done?

Comment: please provide the data after u save to files

Comment: @shadow Please provide it why? It's standard Java Serialization. The data is as per the Object Serialization Specification, Protocol chapter

Comment: @user207421 oh,i just want to see the result cause i think it will need to read byte to byte to get the data.i just watch your solution in the link and it kinda thing i never did before.thanks u.:)

Comment: what i know is FileInputStream and FileOutputStream.Object input stream is pretty good tho.but i think the answer should put the try catch into it.cause maybe when cast the object,it might throw a exception